# hardware specialized for bitmap indexes?

Tags: database, hardware, bitmap, indexing, artificial-intelligence

This is just an out of curiosity question. Let's say you have a database table with 1m rows in it, and you want to often do queries like looking for either male or female, US or non-US, voter or non-voter etc, it's clearly very efficient to define a bitmap index for the table in which each bit represents one either-or condition.

However, to execute the query, you still have to scan through (probably) all of the index doing a bitand to select matching rows.

My question is is there some kind of bitmap-optimized storage such that the bit 'channels' are pre-created in the hardware? I'm envisaging something similar to knitting needles lifting punched cards out of an old library catalog system. In other words, rather than going row by row through memory locations, the chip can just pull out the matching rows electronically because there are hardware connections for each bit channel? I've a feeling the brain must work something like this. If I think of 'all blue objects', and then restrict that to 'all long blue objects' and then 'all long blue heavy objects', my brain does it effortlessly and I'm sure it's not scanning through all the objects I know about every time. It seems like perhaps there is some neurons that provide pathways for different dimensions for quick retrieval. I'm just wondering if there's anything like this in the hardware world?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why invent something that's already there?

[Content-addressable memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory)

Comment: Ah - that's exactly the kind of thing I was wondering about - thank you!

Comment: Looks like I proposed to re-invent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly wire up some logic to perform this (e.g. using [programmable logic devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array)) but you'll need a large number of logic elements and connections, making such circuits probably expensive to build for large databases.

For example, one would have to build matching logic (is this bit being selected on ? what is the required value ?) into each 'row' giving you one signal (selected/not selected) per row.

You would then have a logic circuit with one million output lines (telling you which records were selected) which you probably at some point have to 'serialize' anyway, e.g. when you interface with the PCI bus inside a computer (i.e. first transmit the result for record 0 then 1 etc. or transmit the numbers of the selected records).

As bitwise operations in modern CPUs are fast (should only take one clock cycle for logicl operations such as bitwise `and`, `or` and 'xor') you're probably not gaining much using such a custom circuit compared to optimized software (not mentioning the 'hardware' development and testing effort) unless you have a very special use case.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for your knowledgeable answer. Yep, that does make sense that the cost/benefit probably wouldn't make sense..